# Is it possible to hide qt widget window from other thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Is it possible to hide qt widget window from other thread?
For example if using `ptr->window->hide();`
 from other thread it crashes with error:

> Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread...

Should signals and slots be used in this case or there are easier. alternatives?

Comment: ***Is it possible to hide qt widget window from other thread?*** Yes, use signals and slots for this. Emit a signal from your thread connected to a hide slot in your gui. `QueuedConnection` will handle the cross thread signal/slot connection.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to hide Qt widget window from other thread?

Absolutely, all you need is to connect the signal on your worker thread with the slot on UI thread. And luckily [QWidget::hide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide) is a slot already (not even needed to wrap that in own slot).

```
// in WorkerQObject.h file:
class WorkerQObject : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
     ///
signals:
       void hideUI();
private:
     ///
};

// in WorkerQObject.cpp file:
WorkerQObject::WorkerQObject()
{
    // thread initialization; move to thread etc.
    connect(this, SIGNAL(hideUI()), pWidget, SLOT(hide()));
}

void WorkerQObject::methodOnWorkerThread()
{
    emit hideUI();
}
```

Comment: As an alternative (and to avoid having to define a new signal) you could use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod(pWidget, "hide", Qt::QueuedConnection);`.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod).